# Using VTK.js how to cut a vtkVolume actor arbitrarily?

Tags: javascript, vtk, vtk.js

I am new using VTK.js. I want to achieve a scalpel tool like RadiAnt by using VTK.js.
If it is possible to achieve a scalpel tool like RadiAnt using VTK.js? and how?

I tried to traverse the data and change the data that should be removed, but it was too slow and if in Linear or FastLinear mode the section will be mapped. And I tried clipPlane but only the cutting of convex polygons can be successfully done.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to implement this function by my-self. My solution is: contruct a convex volume polygons to cut the volume.

Comment: I have tried that, It is easy to cut the volume by contructing a convex volume polygons but I  have no idea how to cut the volume by using concave volume polygons.